# Terminal: login(1) or su(1)?

Tags: security, unix, login, resources, terminal

I am on OSX. Can use both *login(1)* or *su(1)* to login as any user.

But, two binaries to make the same job??

Which one consumes less **system resources**?

Which one is less prone to **security risks**?

Which **differences under the hood**?

[ Note, I don't mind gaining root access. I just plan to automate access to accounts on a multi-user, networked *nix. ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`login` starts a shell with a fresh environment, discarding the current one.

`su` starts a shell using the existing environment and modifies only the HOME, USER and SHELL variables.

For example,

```
> export foo=bar
> su <username>
> echo $foo
bar
```

but:

```
> export foo=bar
> login <username>
> echo $foo
```

prints nothing.

AFAIK, `su -l` is equivalent to `login`.

Comment: That's good: _su -l_ is equivalent to _login_ .

What if I need to manage to give access to 300 hundreds accounts at the same time?

_su -l_ is equivalent to _login_ from a "resources consuming" standpoint?

Answer (score 2):

su(1) will create a new shell with the current environment, and once you exit from the subshell, you will be returned to the invoking shell.

login(1) too will create a new shell but with a fresh environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly same job. "su" just changes user who owns current terminal, "login" (as name says) creates new session.

I'm not OSX expert but in all *NIXes important security consideration is to forbid remote direct login to root. It should be only done by "su" after logging in as ordinary user.